# Show selected option in dropdown on edit in Rails Simple Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to make an app with rails 4 and simple form.

When I want to edit a saved project, I am taken back to my form which asks displays the original questions, but without the inputs selected on creation.

Is there a way to set the form so that if you click edit, the previous selections are shown? It looks like I haven't made choices of inputs in the manner in which the edit form is displayed.

For example, one of my questions is:

```
<%= par.select :location,
   options_for_select(["London", "Paris", "Berlin"]),
   label: 'Where will participants take part in this project?',
   prompt: "Choose one",
   class: 'response-project' %>
```

When I check London on create, it saves that choice. When I then press edit, the form displays 'choose one'. It looks like I haven't saved London (which I have - the db shows that choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to set current location as selected option instead of the prompt option:

```
options_for_select(["London", "Paris", "Berlin"], selected: :location)
```

Comment: Thanks Suslov. I'll try it, I only want that to be the case where there is an edit to the project, its fine to display 'choose one' when there is a new project being created

Comment: Great, thanks  - I just tried it. I have to wait 4 minutes to tick this answer as correct. Thank you

Comment: actually, that doesn't work on the objects that are monetised with money-rails gem. Is there a different command for that gem?

Comment: @user2860931: you better ask another question providing this details, I have not worked with this gem